# Constant Data between executions

Tags: c#, variables, static, execution

I have a C# app that uses a DLL I made and I have to store 3 variables inside the DLL that have to be constant so I can get them later even after the user closes the program (I need to get them every execution after I write the data to the DLL). I want to store them inside the DLL because I don't want to use the registry or use any external files so I was thinking of using a Resource file within the DLL to read/write my static data to.

Can anyone give me an example of how to use the resource data like this or suggest another way to do this without declaring hardcoded variables (which I cannot do), or using the registry/external data files to store the information.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [Isolated storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx) to write your data. You can have a quick start [here](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/isolatedstorage/).

Comment: Woah - good find! Love SO for this kind of pointer. (_I have a feeling I'd stay away from this quite frankly, but that's me writing portable code, I suppose_)

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular memory mapped file. Writing to binary executables is bad practice and many (if not all) OS-es will prohibit that in all but the most promiscuous security policy settings.

PS. The popular term for this kind of storage is 'database' (or *program database*). This should help you get a few google hits.

Also, depending on your preferred method of implementation you can use memory-mapping to overlay your data-segment (so you can have your cake and eat it: keep you global static data where it is *and* easily commit them to disk). However, this is more in the C/C++ spirit.

In .NET you'd have to use a giant custom-layout struct (meaning, all reference types are out of the question - this is more unnatural in C# than it is in, say, C++)

So your best bet is probably to use an `UnmanagedMemoryStream`, serialize your data using builtin .NET `System.Runtime.Serialization` (of which the XML flavour is by far the more popular and easily copied from blogs and other sources).

Cheers